# Given a box of dimension W, H and co ordinates of points inside that box. Find the largest area that is free of any of these points

Tags: algorithm, geometry, area

We can find the polygon which either contains all the points or all of them are on the boundary. Then simply calculate the area of this irregular polygon and subtract it from the area of the box. 
This is the solution that I am getting at. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "Find the largest area that is free of any of these points"? The hole box without the points is the largest area.

Comment: You have to define what shape of area you allow. Axis-parallel box, convex polygon, or what? Otherwise, MrSmith42's answer is the solution (but most probably not what you really want).

Comment: I'm not sure of this question that is why I asked this one. This was asked in an interview so the details are not very clear.
Axis-parallel box given, you can assume.

Answer (score 1):

**First attempt:**

Sort all points by increasing X.

Initialize a "best" area, for the moment 0.

For all points by increasing X, let Pj,

- initialize a "free" vertical interval containing no other point than Pj; by default, the full range of ordinates of the points.
- consider all the points to the right of Pj, by increasing X, let Pk.
- if Pk falls outside the free interval, ignore it; else

  - update the free interval (will shrink);
  - evaluate the area of the free rectangle. If better than the best so far, keep it.
  - you can stop the search on the Pj when the area that you would achieve with fictitious points at the abscissa of the rightmost point and the ordinates corresponding to the free interval is lower than the best area.
- at this point, you know the largest empty rectangle having its left side at the abscissa of Pj.

In the end you will know the largest of all.

The procedure will take O(N²) operation at worst (there is a double loop). I am not sure if this is tight or not, given the early termination criterion using the fictitious points.

It is likely that a better time complexity could be achieved, for example by restricting the traversal of the Pk to the free slab. That would require more sophistication.

---

An intermediate stage of the algorithm, after procesing 8 points from Pj (leftmost). The fictitious points are in orange.

[image]

---

**Update:**

For correct handling of the space around the point, one should add the four corners of the domain to the point set.

Comment: I appreciate the effort but could you please explain first two iterations of the given algorithm. I think I got the gist but not the full concept.

Comment: @AjayKumar: which "first two" iterations ?

Comment: how this algorithm will perform for 2 leftmost points so that I can understand algorithm a little bit more.

Comment: @AjayKumar: as the initial free interval is the full vertical range, the second point is valid and the best rectangle will extend upward to the boundary of the domain.

Comment: could you please elaborate more the algorithm. Not getting you.

Comment: @AjayKumar: play it by hand. Pick the leftmost for Pj, and try successive Pk going to the right,and figure out what is the free area left.